# Running jQuery animations serially

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

I have a group of fade out animations, after which I want to run a group of `animation` calls.

How can I make sure one is run after the other?

If I do this:

```
$(div1).fadeOut(600);
$(div2).fadeOut(600);
$(div3).fadeOut(600);

$(div4).animation({opacity:1},600);
$(div5).animation({opacity:1},600);
$(div6).animation({opacity:1},600);
```

The animations run in parallel.

The above code is just a simplification/abstraction of the problem. I can't group all the calls in one function, and in real life there is a variable number of elements, each managed by it's own class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
var deferred = [
    new $.Deferred(),
    new $.Deferred(),
    new $.Deferred()
];

$(div1, div2, div3).each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).fadeOut(600, function() { deferred[i].resolve(); });
});

$.when(deferred[0], deferred[1], deferred[2]).done(function() {
    $(div4, div5, div6).each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).animation({ opacity : 1 }, 600);
    });
});
```

As @Felix pointed out in the comments, a cleaner syntax for the `$.when` would look like this:

```
$.when.apply(null, deferred).done(function() {
    $(div4, div5, div6).each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).animation({ opacity : 1 }, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you meant `two` and `three` on those two lines with `one`

Comment: You can also write `$.when.apply($, deferred).done(...`. This could be a nice plugin...

Comment: @Felix lol.  I started to type that very thing, and then thought "Hmm...  might be too confusing for a beginner" and went with an argument list instead.

Comment: If anyone is interested, @Felix's `.apply` syntax would call the jQuery `when()` function with all of the deferred objects in the array as arguments.

Comment: @stephen - If I read your code correctly, is it similar to:  http://pastebin.com/32i1nRDs  Just so I make sure I understand the idea behind this (beginner and all...:-)

Comment: No, @Itay, not exactly, although the code you have linked to would also work.  In my example, I'm using multiple jQuery Deferred Objects.  Then I'm watching those deferred objects with the `$.when()` method, and applying a callback once all of the objects have resolved.

Comment: @Felix Kling - can you post what you meant, should be usefull

Comment: @Itay: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply to learn more about apply.

Comment: @Stephen: I think it is safer to pass `$` as first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery 1.6+, deferred.pipe() can simplify the code:

```
$.Deferred(function (dfr) {
  dfr
  .pipe(function () { return $(div1).fadeOut(600); })
  .pipe(function () { return $(div2).fadeOut(600); })
  .pipe(function () { return $(div3).fadeOut(600); })
}).resolve();
```

Ref: http://blog.darkthread.net/post-2011-08-03-deferred-pipe-animation.aspx